# standard ml add elements in a custom datatype

Tags: function, types, sml, ml

I want to make a function for a new datatype in Standard ML, the datatype is called intnest, defined as the following:

```
datatype intnest = 
  INT of int
| LIST of intnest list;
```

and I want to make a function that adds all the integers in the intlist, I tried the following code:

```
fun addup (INT n) = n
  | addup (LIST x::xs) = x + addup(xs);
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I also tried the following:

```
fun addup (INT n) = n
  | addup (LIST x::xs) = addup(x) + addup(xs);
```

so that x is of type INT so the first option returns its int value and the addup(xs) is a recursive call to return the same second option.

Also tried the following:

```
fun addup (INT n) = n
  | addup (LIST []) = 0
  | addup (LIST x::xs) = addup(x) + addup(LIST xs);
```

but I get the following error:

```
stdIn:146.4-151.50 Error: parameter or result constraints of clauses don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  this clause:      intnest list -> 'Z
  previous clauses:      intnest -> 'Z
  in declaration:
    addup =
      (fn INT n => n
        | LIST nil => 0
        | :: (<pat>,<pat>) => addup <exp> + addup <exp>)
stdIn:151.25-151.50 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: intnest
  operand:         intnest list
  in expression:
    addup x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a syntax error in the `LIST` case; get rid of the `of`. You'll want the case to look like `addup (LIST(x::xs)) = ...`.

More substantially, there are conceptual problems in `addup`. The desired type of `addup` appears to be `intnest -> int`. It's thus necessary to ensure that `addup` is always applied to `intnest` values and returning `int` values.

Now consider the type of the elements of the list `x::xs`. You defined it as `LIST of intnest list`, so `x` is an `intnest`. But in `addup`, you treat `x` as an integer.

Along the same lines, `xs` is a `intnest list`, but that's not an `intnest`, which is what you're treating it as in `addup(xs)`. Your revised version addresses the problem with `x`, but not that with `xs`. You need to make an `intnest` from `xs` using `LIST`, which means you'll need to use `addup(LIST xs)`.

Finally, you are missing a case. What happens when you have `LIST []`?

The third version doesn't work because you're missing needed parentheses. The compiler is telling you that you're using a `intnest list` as one of the cases (the `::` case). That is, it sees `LIST x::xs` as `(LIST x) :: xs`.

Comment: I didnt quite understand you, isnt xs a list of intnest?

Comment: @aizen92 Yes, that's exactly what it is. But the type you need for `addup` is `intnest`. Your `LIST` case is *implemented* using an `intnest list`, but is *not* an `intnest list`. It might help to compare the types of `xs` and `LIST xs`.

Comment: The problem was with the brackets between x::xs, But I'm not quite understanding why is that, isnt x::xs considered as one onject that is a list?

Comment: @aizen92 `::` is a type constructor for lists, analogous to `LIST` and `INT` in your `intnest` datatype. SML uses that to deconstruct the list when pattern matching. This is why that case for `::` shows up in the error message.